# Autopostback not updating updatePanels in IE6

Tags: asp.net, ajax

having an issue supporting IE6 (meh)..

I have an update panel that is triggered by radio buttons.  Its pretty straightforward.. show a form if one button it clicked, or another form if another button is clicked.  In IE 7, 8, Firefox, etc. this works fine.

In IE6, the radiobutton selection doesnt update the form.  If I make a selection, then click the submit button, when the page reloads it will be in it's desired state (meaning the correct form will show). So it's almost like the AutoPostback isnt firing to update the page.

Has anyone encountered this issue?  Thanks In Advance..

Here's a shortened sample of what Im running into:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updrdoBuyingFor" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdoBuyingFor" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoBuyingFor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
        <asp:ListItem Text="I am buying for someone else" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="It's for me" Value="2" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</ContentTemplate>
```

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updMyInfo" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMyInfo_Country" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBtnContinue" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdoBuyingFor" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...Code for Form A...
    </ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updFriendsInfo" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlMyInfo_Country" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgBtnContinue" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdoBuyingFor" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...Code for Form B...
    </ContentTemplate>
```

In response to @Pabuc below, Im setting the visible property of the table in "Code for Form A\B" to true or false depending on the radio button selection.

Comment: Yes, you need to post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attributing this issue to the same question\answer I posted here: [asp net 4 - autopostback doesnt fire in ie6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4433746/asp-net-4-autopostback-doesnt-fire-in-ie6)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem with combobox.

What I did was instead of making the combobox visible, invisible, I made the tablerow visible invisible. I'm sure it'll work for you too. If you have more than 1 cells in your row, make the cell visible/invisible.

Let me know if it works.